# How do I remove broken miniport drivers on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, drivers

I have a Windows XP machine with two network cards and the drivers for a third, disconnected network card installed.

In addition to the virtual network stuff from VMWare Player, I was using some VPN software that clashed with some Wifi access point software (Connectify). Connectify won't install or uninstall properly... now there are two Connectify Miniport device drivers, six Deterministic Network Enhancer miniport drivers, a MAC Bridge Miniport and Packet Scheduler Miniport all listed in the Device Manager under Network Adapters.

All of them are listed with an exclamation mark as "Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)" or "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)".

Attempting to remove any of the miniport devices results in Windows saying something about how they are protected because they're probably needed for Windows to boot.

How in the blazes do I get rid of these things?

Comment: Start with booting into 'Safe Mode' and trying from there.

Comment: Well, Safe Mode allowed me to remove the two Connectify miniports and the MAC Bridge miniport, but the rest remain. I tried reinstalling the Deterministic Network Enhancer as per Citrix's instructions, but they're all still broken and unremovable.